# How to run a method in FactoryBot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm quite excited to make a `find_or_create_by` version of factorybot factories. However, I want to add the code to a factory with one line (e.g. an include statement, or a method call) instead of pasting a whole block in to each factory.

So I'm trying to insert a method into FactoryBot, but the factory just complains that the method's name is not a registered trait. How can I call a method from a factory?

```
class FactoryBot::Declaration::Implicit
  def change_factory_to_find_or_create
    # This hook allows us to do find_or_create for factories
    to_create do |instance|
      attributes = instance.class.find_or_create_by(instance.attributes.compact).attributes
      instance.attributes = attributes.except('id')
      instance.id = attributes['id'] # id can't be mass-assigned
      instance.instance_variable_set('@new_record', false) # marks record as persisted
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_thing do
    change_factory_to_find_or_create

    label { "Label One" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the wrong class is being opened. It should be:

```
class FactoryBot::DefinitionProxy
  def my_custom_method
    ...
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_thing do
    my_custom_method

    label { "My Label" }
  end
end
```